# What is Microsoft Remode Desktop (RDP) unexpected error code 4399?

Tags: macos, networking, rdp

I tried to connect to a server using Microsoft Remote Desktop client on OSX. As it was set to fullscreen mode it would just show a black screen and shut down immediatly. So I removed fullscreen mode and tried to connect and I received an error:

[image]

Of course, I tried to find the right meaning behind this error code with highly scientific methods (google), but I was unable to find anything about this kind of message.

Later, I managed to connect to server through that same client, but I noticed that from time to time black small black rectangle would appear in apps. Like when I selected a part of SQL in SQL Server Management Studio, a black rectangle would appear right bellow the selection. Another example is that a window of the app would just go transparent except a few bits of text or icon.

Does anyone have any idea what could this be or where to search for answers?